# FloatingActionButton over EditText is not clickable

Tags: java, android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I have a FloatingActionButton over a big EditText. When I launch the app and try to tap on the FloatingActionButton the keyboard flips up because it takes the tap of the EditText.

What do I need to change in my code such that the FloatingActionButton is "above" the EditText?

I found that I need to add the FloatingActionButton last, what I already did, such that it is on top, but it didn't work. I also have implemented an onClickListener, which I suppose is not the problem.

Here a screenshot of my layout: [Layout Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUjFS.png)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/listviewbackground"
        android:backgroundTint="#80FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTintMode="src_over"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:hint="What do you need to do?"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/itemTitle"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/DueDate"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Due Date"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Date"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Date"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="33dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.2"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:onClick="openCalendarView"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Important"
                android:layout_width="149dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Is important?"
              android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/DueDate"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switch1"
                android:layout_width="51dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Important"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.59"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Important"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Date"></Switch>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/constraintLayout1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="Put in your description"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/Description"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/Description"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingButtonDone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/check"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/Green"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/Description"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>



Here my onClickListener

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_itemdetail, container, false);

        //Getting Data and Creation of ToDoItem Object
        FloatingActionButton floatingbutton = view.findViewById(R.id.floatingButtonDone);
        floatingbutton.bringToFront();
        floatingbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Getting Data
                try {
                    //Do something
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "You need to set a Title", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }

            }


        });
```

Comment: please share your layout screenshot. I will redesign according to your screenshot

Comment: @propoLis I added the screenshot above as link. Thanks

Comment: ok please wait , I redesigning it now

Comment: @propoLis thanks for your time!

Comment: Welcome! Where is your Date textView location in screenshot

Comment: Can you just align the button to viewport rather than to EditText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your FloatingActionButton inside a frame layout and set its gravity and padding accordingly where you want to show it.

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingButtonDone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
            android:backgroundTint="@color/Green"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:gravity="bottom|end"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/check" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Great idea, this helped. Using different layouts worked out for me. Thanks